# Grothendieck Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}$ be a ring, $K=\mathbb{Q}$ its field of fractions, $L$ a number field, and $B = \mathcal{O}_L$, the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Define the category $C_A$ of $A$-modules of finite length via composition series.

If $M\in \text{obj} (C_A)$, $M\not = 0$, write composition series, 
$$ 0 = M_0 \subset M_1 \subset ... \subset M_n = M $$
Since each $M_j/M_{j-1}$ is simple we can say that $M_j/M_{j-1} = A/\mathfrak{p}_j$ for some prime ideal. Furthermore, this choice of ideal is not ambiguous, there is only one such $\mathfrak{p}_j$ we can pick, as they are characterized by the prime numbers. The ideal product $\prod_j \mathfrak{p}_j$ is then well-defined as a consequence of the Jordan-Holder theorem. Thus, we have defined a "function" $f:  \text{obj} (C_A) \to I_A$ by $f(M) = \prod_j \mathfrak{p}_j$, where $I_A$ is the ideal group of $A$.

My question is, why is the function $g:  \text{obj} (C_B) \to I_B$, defined in a similar way, well-defined? The difficulty comes from the following observation. If $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{b}'$ divide $\mathfrak{p}$, and their residue-class degrees are equal then $B/\mathfrak{b} = B/\mathfrak{b}'$ (as fields over $A/\mathfrak{p}$). Thus, it seems there is choice in how we choose the prime ideals in $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm getting something wrong (if yes, please tell me, in particular if you decide to downvote), but the same argument works for the construction of $\text{obj}(C_B)\to I_B$ as well - there's nothing related to $A$ in it.

More generally, if ${\mathcal O}$ is a Dedekind ring and ${\mathscr A}$ is the category of finite length modules over ${\mathcal O}$, then:

1. The Jordan-Hoelder Theorem establishes an isomorphism of abelian groups $\textsf{K}_0({\mathscr A})\cong {\mathbb Z}^{(\text{m-Spec}({\mathcal O}))}$ as the simples in ${\mathscr A}$ are, up to isomorphism, precisely the ${\mathcal O}/{\mathfrak p}$ for ${\mathfrak p}\in\text{Spec}({\mathcal O})\setminus\{(0)\}$.
2. By the definition of Dedekind domains in terms of unique factorization of ideals, $I_{\mathcal O}\cong{\mathbb Z}^{(\text{m-Spec}({\mathcal O}))}$.

Everything sits in a commutative square
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \text{obj}({\mathscr A}) & \longrightarrow & \textsf{K}_0({\mathscr A}) \\ \downarrow && {\scriptsize\cong\hskip0.5mm}\downarrow\\ I_{\mathcal O} & \stackrel{\cong}{\longrightarrow}& {\mathbb Z}^{(\text{m-Spec}({\mathcal O}))}\end{array},$$
in which the left vertical map $$\text{obj}({\mathscr A})\to\textsf{K}_0({\mathscr A})\to{\mathbb Z}^{(\text{m-Spec}({\mathcal O}))}\to I_{\mathcal O}$$ is the map you're looking for. See

> ***Serre, Local Fields**, Chapter I, §5: The Norm and Inclusion Homomorphisms*

where also the construction of Norm and Inclusion Homomorphisms associated to extensions of Dedekind rings are discussed both in terms of the ideal group and in terms of the Grothendieck group.

Comment: *sigh* Could the downvoter please comment?

Comment: It was not me! I did not yet carefully read your response, mr Hanno. Maybe it had to do with: if $B/\mathfrak{b} \sim B/\mathfrak{b}'$ then $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{b}'$. That claim was never proven (from my quick reading of your response).

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: My answer concerns your question as to whether $\text{obj}(C_B)\to I_B$ can be constructed in the same way as $\text{obj}(C_A)\to I_A$, and the answer is *yes* - it's the same for any Dedekind ring. But maybe that's not *really* what you were asking for?

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you mr Hanno, but there is something I do not quite understand. Let $B$ be Dedekind. If the quotient of B by two primes gives isomorphic modules then why must it follows that the two primes were equal?

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: If $A$ is any commutative ring and ${\mathfrak p}$ is a prime, then the module $A/{\mathfrak p}$ determines ${\mathfrak p}$ as the annihilator of any of its non-zero elements.

Comment: Dear mr Hanno. Let $A=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, this is a commutative ring. Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $\mathfrak{p} = 0 \times p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{q} = p\mathbb{Z}\times 0$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ are both prime ideals of $A$ with $A/\mathfrak{p}$ isomorphic to $A/\mathfrak{q}$ as an $A$-module.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: No - they are isomorphic as abelian groups, but not as $A$-modules (which are ordered pairs of abelian groups).

Comment: Dear mr Hanno, I checked the group isomorphism to see if it extends to a module one. You are correct, it is not a module isomorphism. I will try doing what you said about annihilators to recover the equal ideals.

Comment: Dear, mr Hanno beloved. I used your suggestion to use annihilators, it worked out very simply. I can see now that this has nothing to do with Dedekind domains, but in fact an arbitrary ring. Thank you.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: You're welcome - could you then close the question?